# Display Value in cell Y based on greater than, less than of cell X

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

Here's the scenario. I have a large spreadsheet of candidates for NHS at my school that are given a score by several teachers, community members, etc. I average out their score and then based on that number they are given a score/value from a rubric. I am looking for a formula that will read the value of cell X (their average score) and display a specific value in cell Y(their rubric score). The following is the criteria:

value<2.0, display 0

value>2.0  value<3.0, display 1

value>3.0  value<3.5, display 2

value>3.5  value<3.75, display 3

value>3.75, display 4

I tried looking this up and the closest I found was a formula that I modified to look like this:

`=IF(I10="AVERAGE_CHARACTER",IF(I10<2,0,IF(AND(I10>2,I11<3),1,IF(AND(I10>3,I11<3.5),2,IF(AND(I10>3.5,I11<3,75),3,IF(I11>3.75,4,0))))))`

All it says is FALSE in the cell. Not sure if I'm using the wrong formula or have a typo in the formula. Thoughts? If there is an alternate or easier method, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks!

source: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/575953-greater-than-x-but-less-than-y.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you keep the thresholds and the rubric in separate arrays:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,2,3,3.5,3.75},{0,1,2,3,4})
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Just placed the formula in a cell below the "average score" and replaced "A1" with what ever the cell above is called.Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like: (value to be changed in `A1`)

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,{0,0;2,1;3,2;3.5,3;3.75,4},2)
```

or having a table like this: (value to be changed in `C1`)

```
  |   A   |   B   |
1 |   0   |   0   |
2 |   2   |   1   |
3 |   3   |   2   |
4 |  3.5  |   3   |
5 |  3.75 |   4   |

=VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B5,2)
```